# How do create a list of amount of raw input lines using sys.stdin

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write code for kattis using idle and am having trouble creating a list of the amount of lines input. Here is an example input:

2 1
carrots?
bunnies

I want to create a list that would give me `list[0]` would give me `"2 1"`.

Answer (score 0):

Just print out the second number in the input, everything else is merely a distraction, assuming this is for `carrots` on kattis.